# Java performance vs. code-style: Making multiple method calls from the same line of code

Tags: java, performance, coding-style

I am curious whether packing multiple and/or nested method calls within the same line of code is better for performance and that is why some developers do it, at the cost of making their code less readable.

E.g.

```
//like
Set<String> jobParamKeySet = jobParams.keySet();
Iterator<String> jobParamItrtr = jobParamKeySet.iterator();
```

Could be also written as

```
//dislike    
Iterator<String> jobParamItrtr = jobParams.keySet().iterator();
```

Personally, I hate the latter because it does multiple evaluations in the same line and is hard for me to read the code.  That is why I try to **avoid by all means** to have more than one evaluation per line of code.  I also don't know that `jobParams.keySet()` returns a `Set` and that bugs me.
Another example would be:

```
//dislike
Bar.processParameter(Foo.getParameter());
```

vs

```
//like
Parameter param = Foo.getParameter();
Bar.processParameter(param);
```

The former makes me noxious and dizzy as I like to consume simple and clean evaluations in every line of code and I just hate it when I see other people's code written like that.

**But are there any (performance) benefits to packing multiple method calls in the same line?**

EDIT:  Single liners are also more difficult to debug, thanks to @stemm for reminding

Comment: Did you try to compile the two codes into byte code and see the difference? It's a good practice to get familiar with the language "behind the scenes".

Comment: The compiler probably fixes it so that it doesn't make a difference (in most cases)

Comment: what would the byte comparison tell me and how would i look at it?

Comment: Also its hard to debug one-line-written code.

Comment: And one more (important) thing: Leave micro optimizations for compilers - do whatever you (and your team) find more readable. Readability is for programmers, optimization is for compilers.

Comment: I think you will find that all those example end up as the same byte-code.

Comment: @stemm --spot on, i was thinking of that too but forgot to mention

Comment: The 'all on one line' example is often referred to as 'train wreck' code, e.g.: http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/how-many-train-wrecks-are-lurking-in-your-code/

Comment: This is purely a taste issue. In FP everything is a composition of functions and what blue-collar Java devs call "train-wreck code" they call just "code". The more code I read and write, the more I prefer this style because every local variable introduced is another item that I need to keep track of, and the human short-term memory only has capacity for 6-7 such items.

Comment: Functional Programming. The "one evaluation per line" style results in  "connect-the-dots" code that is much harder for me to track. When an evaluation happens at its single use site, its purpose is dead obvious.

Comment: well, the example is obviously in Java...  anyway, as far as "blue-collar Java devs", might not be a bad idea to get off your high horse

Comment: James Gosling himself said that Java's design goal was to be a "blue collar language". I'm only refering to that. As it turned out, Java really is a raging success as a blue-collar language.

Comment: so, Marko, I'm just curious:  where do you cut the limit for how many evals you wanna have on a single line?  if one is too simple for you, where do you draw the line?  a dozen consecutive calls all piped into one another perhaps?

Comment: That is obviously mandated by program logic. As a general rule, everything that can compose, let it compose. Note also that it is not necessarily calls piped one after the other; composition can happen at the argument list site within the parens as well. BTW for the record my line is limited at 100 chars (120 at the most, but constant for every project). I am nazistically strict about enforcing that.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik, don't forget that in functional languages generally functions does not perform side effects, and its easy to trace data through entire chain of calls. But the opposite situation in imperative languages, where some method can cause Big Bang (or just simply return null, which causes NullPointerException :) which would explode the tail of chain calls

Comment: @stemm A very good point---and exactly why I design my methods to be side-effect-free, not to arbitrarily return `null`, and to behave reasonably for `null` arguments. This is all just a matter of design choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Micro optimization is killer. If the code references you are showing are either instance scope (or) method scope, I would go with second approach.

Method scope variables will be eligible for GC as soon as method execution done, so even you declare another variable, it's ok because scope is limited and the advantage you get will be readable and main-table code.

Comment: Also, due to escape analysis in jvm - there are many cases when local variables might be created not in heap, but in the call stack. And after returning from method, they would disappear without help of GC. So, I mean that in many cases local variables doesn't cause performance overhead at all (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis)

Answer (score 5):

I tend to disagree with most others on this list.  I actually find the first way cleaner and easier to read.

In your example:

```
//like
Set<String> jobParamKeySet = jobParams.keySet();
Iterator<String> jobParamItrtr = jobParamKeySet.iterator();
Could be also written as

//dislike    
Iterator<String> jobParamItrtr = jobParams.keySet().iterator();
```

the first method (the one you like) has a lot of irrelevant information.  The whole point of the iterator interface, for example, is to give you a standard interface that you can use to loop over whatever backing implementation there is.  So the fact that it is a keyset has no bearing on the code itself.  All you are looking for is the iterator to loop over the implemented object.

Secondly, the second implementation actually gives you more information.  It tells you that the code will be ignoring the implementation of jobParams and that it will only be looping through the keys.  In the first code, you must first trace back what jobParamKeySet is (as a variable) to figure out what you are iterating over.  Additionally, you do not know if/where jobParamKeySet is used elsewhere in the scope.

Finally, as a last comment, the second way makes it easier to switch implementations if necessary; in the first case, you might need to recode two lines (the first variable assignment if it changes from a set to something else), whereas the second case you only need to change out one line.

That being said, there are limits to everything.  Chaining 10 calls within a single line can be complicated to read and debug.  However 3 or 4 levels is usually clear.  Sometimes, especially if an intermediary variable is required several times, it makes more sense to declare it explicitly.

In your second example:

```
//dislike
Bar.processParameter(Foo.getParameter());
vs

//like
Parameter param = Foo.getParameter();
Bar.processParameter(param);
```

I find it actually more difficult to understand exactly which parameters are being processed by `Bar.processParameter(param)`.  It will take me longer to match `param` to the variable instantiation to see that it is `Foo.getParameter()`.  Whereas the first case, the information is very clear and presented very well - you are processing `Foo.getParameter()` params.  Personally, I find the first method is less prone to error as well - it is unlikely that you accidentally use `Foo2.getParamter()` when it is within the same call as opposed to a separate line.

Comment: I completely agree. When reading someone else's code, each variable declared is yet another thing I have to mentally track. As long as the line doesn't get too long, I prefer chaining method calls.

Comment: +1 Excellent writing, many good arguments. I even overlooked the point  that a redundant var also needs a redundant type declaration. To be fair, this can easily be avoided by using the most general applicable interface---but, on the other hand, it can be completely messed up as well, using a very detailed implementation type.

Comment: "However 3 or 4 levels is usually clear".  Maybe clear, but dangerous.  What is there's an NPE somewhere in that 4 level chain?  At which part was the NPE?  Method chaining is often hard to test and also poses the NPE threat.

Answer (score 3):

There is one less variable assignment, but even the compiler can optimize it in some cases.
I would not do it for performance, it is kind of an [early optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Write the code that is easier to maintain.

In my case, I find:

```
Iterator<String> jobParamItrtr = jobParams.keySet().iterator();
```

easier to be read than:

```
Set<String> jobParamKeySet = jobParams.keySet();
Iterator<String> jobParamItrtr = jobParamKeySet.iterator();
```

But I guess it is a matter of personal taste.

Comment: This is trivial to optimize even at the bytecode level, so we can practically assume the redundant var **will** be optimized away. Not that I would ever use such a chatty code style, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Code is never developed by same user. I would choose second way. Also it is easier to understand and maintain.

Also This is beneficial when two different teams are working on the code at different locations.

Many times we take an hour or more time to understand what other developer has done, if he uses first option. Personally I had this situation many times.

Answer (score 1):

> But are there any (performance) benefits to packing multiple method calls in the same line?

I seriously doubt the difference is measurable but even if there were I would consider

> is hard for me to read the code.

to be so much more important it cannot be over stated.

Even if the it were half the speed, I would still write the simplest, cleanest and easiest to understand code and only when you have profiled the application and identified that you have an issue would I consider optimising it.

BTW: I prefer the more dense, chained code, but I would suggest you use what you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

The omission of an extra local variable probably has a neglible performance advantage (although the JIT may be able to optimize this).

Personally I don't mind call chaining when its pretty clear whats done and the intermediate object is very unlikely to be null (like your first 'dislike'-example). When it gets complex (multiple .'s in the expression), I prefer explicit local variables, because its so much simpler to debug.

So I decide case by case what I prefer :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where `a().b().c().d` is that much harder to read than `a.b.c.d` which people don't seem to mind too much. (Though I would break it up.)
If you don't like that it's all on one line, you could say

```
a()
 .b()
 .c()
 .d
```

(I don't like that either.)
I prefer to break it up, using a couple extra variables.
It makes it easier to debug.

If performance is your concern (as it should be), the first thing to understand is not to sweat the small stuff.
If adding extra local variables costs anything at all, the rest of the code has to be rippin' fat-free before it even begins to matter.